# How to read a json file stored in c drive using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I want to read a json file stored in C:/Program Files/Sample/demo.json 
using JQuery.
I am using the following code but it is not picking the file. I want to read it only from that path.

```
$.getJSON("C:/Program Files/Sample/demo.json",function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: `C:/Program Files/Sample/demo.json` looks to me like a local path. Are you running this on a server? or on your dev environment?

Comment: You cannot make an AJAX request to the local filesystem for very obvious security reasons. Run your code on a webserver and use a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're doing this from a page loaded via `http:` or `https:`, you can't do this. It would be a major security issue.

**If** you're doing this from a file loaded via a `file:` URL, some browsers will allow it, and others won't. For instance, Chrome doesn't, Firefox does.

In general, better to use a web server (even if a locally-installed one) for web tasks, and serve both the page and the JSON file through it.

Answer (score 0):

`C:/Program Files/Sample/demo.json` is an absolute path, not a relative path. When building web applications, you need to use a relative path, from your Javasctipt source (`.js` files) to your target files (`.json` file).

For example, if you keep both files in the same directory, just use:

```
$.getJSON("demo.json", ....)
```

If you put the `.json` file in a `json` directory under your root directory, you should use:

```
$.getJSON("/json/demo.json", ....)
```

Read more about relative paths [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).